# Can we open ContextMenu on right click of the worksheet?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/officemenu?view=excel-js-1.17

In above document URL specified that OfficeMenu has tow type Id one for row, second for column and third for selected text in sheet.

Is there any way to open that context menu on click of the right click of the worksheet?